# How does the polynomial $X^{p-1}+1$ split over $\mathbb{F}_p$

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields

Is there a well-known formula for the irreducible factors of the polynomial $X^{p-1}+1$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ where $p$ is an odd prime? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It factorizes as $(x^2+a_1)\cdots (x^2+a_r)$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde thanks, that was exactly what I needed. Is it easy to show that?

Comment: It is sufficient to find quadratic non-residues mod p. Then you've to determine the number of them : ((p-1)/2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its irreducible factors are
$$X^2-r$$
(at least when $p$ is odd)
as $r$ runs through the quadratic non-residues modulo $p$.

This follows, say, from Euler's criterion for the Legendre symbol.

Answer (score 2):

You can write for $p$ odd prime :

$$ X^{p-1} + 1 = \prod_{ a , (\frac{a}{p})=-1}(X^2-a)  \mod p$$

With :

$$ (\dfrac{a}{p})=-1 $$ denotes the Legender symbol that is $-1$ if $a$ is not a quadratic residues $ \mod p$

Then I used Euler criterion :

$$  (\dfrac{a}{p})=a^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \mod p $$